# R cran, How to create a new single Factor from the Factors in different rows in column B, depending on a Factor in another column A

Tags: r, dataframe

It is probably a silly question, but I did not get it done and could not find this problem elsewhere.

I want a dataset like this:

```
A     B
green lizard
blue  paper
blue  stone
blue  scissor
red   spock
red   stone
```

Turn into this:

```
A     B
green lizard
blue  paper, stone, scissor
red   spock, stone
```

I could do it with subsets, but A has too many factors. My loop also did not work. Maybe someone has a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

See `ddply` from `plyr`

```
dat <- read.table(text='A     B
green lizard
blue  paper
blue  stone
blue  scissor
red   spock
red   stone',header=TRUE)

library(plyr)

ddply(dat,.(A),summarise,nn = list(paste(B)))
# 
# A                    nn
# 1  blue paper, stone, scissor
# 2 green                lizard
# 3   red          spock, stone
```

#### EDIT using dplyr

For some reason it expects a single length value in summarise so I  collpase the result in one string.

```
library(dplyr)
dat  %.%
  group_by(A) %.%
  summarise(nn = paste(B,collapse=','))

      A                  nn
1  blue paper,stone,scissor
2 green              lizard
3   red         spock,stone
```